# SQL Numeric/Date Pattern Analytics/Timespans

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, datediff

I'm building an product based on weekday analytics. Essentially, data will be populating into a table on various days of the week for different products, and I'm trying to see if the data population date follows a specific pattern, and if so, I'd like COUNT the number of consecutive days in this pattern.

For example:

Product ABCD, over the last six months, has had data populated on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, each week (weekdays 2, 4, and 6).

I'd like to know, how many consecutive days (Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays) the data has been populated. For example, if over the last 4 weeks, we have had an update on every Mon, Wed, and Fri, the number of consecutive 'days' would be 12 (three days each week * 4).

For the weekday data (matching each product to the weekday numbers with entries), I've shaped the data like this (if scripts are needed, I can send too, however, most of my data is still raw so I need help shaping it):

[image]

Comment: I think I might want to use statistical software rather than SQL for something like this.

Comment: Good point, however, for now, we are limited to SQL for this task.

Comment: Google `SQL Gaps and Islands` for some ideas about how to handle this kind of logic in SQL.

Comment: You can use trigger after table insert to insert in another statistical table with information when did the insert occur

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this to get you in the ballpark:

```
select Year,WeekNumber --Both DimDate values
    , Count(*) Ct
from dimdate DD  -- This is table that has every date in it
  join [Your Table] on DD.Date = [Your Table].LoadDate
where DD.DayNumberOfWeek in (2,4,6)
group by Year,WeekNumber
order by Year,WeekNumber
```

This will get you a count by week (you are hoping to see 3) where a load happened on Mon, Wed , or Fri.